# Does Azure MariaDB support admin user authentication with Azure AD?

Tags: mariadb, azure

I did not find that is documented for MariaDB. I see no open MariaDB Jira issues about this either, but I'm wondering if the community knows if it works or if any MariaDB customizations are needed to support it.

NOTE: [Azure AD auth is supported by Azure MySQL][1].
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mysql/single-server/concepts-azure-ad-authentication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure MySQL exposes an Authentication blad under the Settings left menu.

MariaDB does not so I'm going to go with NO this is not supported.